# How can I make views page with unique dates?

Tags: 7, views

I've made views page with node titles and dates:

```
Title       Post date
node1125    2016-08-09
node1137    2016-08-09
node1138    2016-08-09
node1139    2016-08-10 
node1140    2016-08-10
node1141    2016-08-10
node1142    2016-08-13
node1143    2016-08-13
```

How can I make views page for these nodes with unique dates only:

```
2016-08-09
2016-08-10
2016-08-13
```

?

Comment: Try using Grouping in views -> format -> table -> Grouping field Nr.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made grouping (agregation) on date field.
Then I override **views-view-unformatted.tpl.php** for the view with

```
<?php print $title; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i fully understand your question. However, assuming you want to simply have a list of dates.

Edit the view 
Make sure the format uses fields 
In the field section add or remove field as required (fields can be removed using the rearrange menu item , under the arrow next to add)

Comment: Well. Not just a list of dates but unique dates. Now I'm trying to use views-view-grouping.tpl.php for group theming. But I hope there is more smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by trying aggregation on the date field

Comment: Yes. I've made it. And now I'm trying to use views-view-grouping.‌​tpl.php for group theming. But I hope there is more smart solution.

Comment: Nice, yeah I'd like to learn a smarter one as well :)